# Mongo is using 5-7% of CPU, so why is my computer so slow?

Tags: mongodb

I've installed MongoDB (not sharded, single location) on an AWS EC2 instance, and I'm finding that when I'm running large insert operations via pymongo, my entire EC2 instance gets very sluggish. Yet when I check CPU usage, it's reasonably low. Why is this and is there any way to contain it? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Since you doing an insert, i'm guessing spike is on your disk.

Comment: What ec2 instance type are you using?  Use "iostat -x 1" to see how much disk operations are used.

Comment: CPU generally isn't the limiting factor for MongoDB, particularly if you are doing simple inserts. If the whole instance is slow, I/O and memory are more likely resource constraints .. you need to look at metrics such as iostat and page faults. You also haven't indicated your EC2 instance type or storage configuration, but I wouldn't have any great performance expectations for free tier or low cost instances (eg. micro & small ).

Answer (score 1):

1. Use 'mongostat' to monitor the amount of inserts
2. Use 'iostat -x 1' to see how much of the disk limitation is used. 'top'/'htop' to see cpy/ram limitations. 'nethogs' for network limits.
3. If the disk limit isn't reached : Let your python script run from different locations (servers) at the same time, and see if you can increase the amount of inserts. The pymongo driver might have a limitation per connection also.

Or you can use the mongoclient as extra threads. But I found the mongo client even slower inserting than pymongo on my tests:

```
$ mongo testDB --eval "for( var i = 0; i < 50000; i++ ) { db.test.insert({x:i,y:'hi'}); }" &

$ mongo testDB --eval "for( var i = 0; i < 50000; i++ ) { db.test.insert({x:i,y:'hi'}); }" &
```

Python speed insert test:

```
import sys
import datetime

from pymongo import MongoClient
connection = MongoClient("mongodb://10.x.x.x", w=0)

db=connection.testing
test = db.test

tstart = datetime.datetime.now()
d = {'counter' : 0}
while d['counter'] < 1000000:
  d['counter'] += 1
  testjs = {"x":d['counter'], "y":"hi" }
  try:
    test.insert(testjs)
  except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]

tend = datetime.datetime.now()
tdiff = tend - tstart
print tdiff.total_seconds(), ' ',tdiff.microseconds
```

Todo extra in the python script:

- connect to mongos with a sleep between the inserts to see what happens when a primary of a shard goes down
- insert more than "hi" to test splitting of chunks
- ...